# how to display current user's name in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, authentication

Please tell me how to get current user and how to display loggedin users name in Asp.net using C#. Please tell me ASAP

Comment: are you using membership provider?

Answer (score 1):

```
var username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

Comment: FYI this will only work if the application in question requires authorization. On a public site, this will be empty.

Comment: @SouthShoreAK that is obviously assumed. how else will you get a current users name - without asking?

Comment: I figured you knew. I was adding it for the benefit of the person asking the question. I see questions quite often from people trying to get the user name from an anonymous site.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview.aspx#Y0 Loginview control on a page

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" Runat="server">
  <LoggedInTemplate>
   <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" Runat="server" 
                  FormatString ="Welcome, {0}" />
   <br />
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" Runat="server" 
      NavigateUrl="~/MemberPages/ChangePassword.aspx">
      Change Password
    </asp:HyperLink>
  </LoggedInTemplate>
  <AnonymousTemplate>
    <asp:Login id="Login1" runat="server" 
        CreateUserText="Create a new user..."
        CreateUserUrl="~/Register.aspx" 
        PasswordRecoveryUrl="~/Recovery.aspx" 
        UserNameLabelText="E-mail address:" />
  </AnonymousTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```